# How to make SKEmitter node fire only once?

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm making a game and I want to have some particle effects. But I have a problem, my emitters spawn particles indefinitely, like a stream that never stops.
So far I worked around that by showing emitter for small amount of time, like 0.1 second.

But I want it to spawn needed amount of particles and stop at this, watch the particles end their lifetime and that's it. For example explosion, or something hitting the ground, raising dirt, and so on.

I know the basics of SKEmitter node, I have everything set up, I just want to know how to achieve this effect.

What is the way to do this in Sprite Kit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Sprite Kit for a while, but I believe you need to set the

**Max Number of Particles**, to anything other than zero.

By default it is 0, which means continue for ever.

[image]

Don't forget to remove the node after it has completed.